# How to mock a set method in Java to get correct boolean return type using PowerMockito?

Tags: java, junit, junit4, powermockito

I want to write JUnit for a method that is executed based upon a boolean value like:

```
if(this.getTypePanel().isPanelTypeABC()){
    //someOperation
}
else{
  //otherOperation
}
```

where `this.getTypePanel` returns `LoadPanel`. Mocking it in my test class:

```
@Mock
LoadPanel loadPanel;
```

So in test class, I somehow want to set `loadPanel.setTypePanel("ABC")`,
so that above condition `this.getTypePanel().isPanelTypeABC()` will evaluate to `true` or `false` based on what I am setting.

What can be the simplest way to do this?

Comment: you're not testing LoadPanel, so you wouldn't call setTypePanel but mock isPanelTypeABC() to return true or false

Comment: that is not working so was looking for this approach.

Comment: you're not showing enough info, do you use Spring or something, do you use the right Runner, did you set the mock to the unit under test, do you annotate InsertMocks or something?

Comment: @Ssk92 you should show your code, to expect a proper answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Would that work?

```
when(loadPanel.isPanelTypeABC()).thenReturn(true)
```

Comment: tried that the very first time but that is not working. I am getting NullPointer.

Answer (score 0):

Mocking LoadPanel will not be enough. Are you also injectngMock to the class for which the test are for?

If you are, Can you tell us if Load Panel is stored as a global object in the class? If that is the case we can use the following to set it manually:

```
LoadPanel abcLoadPanel = new LoadPanel;
abcLoadPanel.setTypePanel("ABC")
ReflectionTestUtils.setField(className, loadPanel, abcLoadPanel);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your idea is not quite good for a ***unit*** test. You should never depend on the behavior of any outside class if you going to run a proper unit test.

However giving a solution to your problem, I assume `typePanel` is a private member of your class. So You can do something like this.

```
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.mockito.InjectMocks;
import org.mockito.Mock;
import org.mockito.junit.MockitoJUnitRunner;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.when;

@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class MyClassTest {
    @Mock
    private LoadPanel typePanel;
    @InjectMocks
    private MyClass myClass;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        when(typePanel.isPanelTypeABC()).thenReturn(true);
    }
}
```